# Smart counting of id in join mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement, count, sum, case

Upon running this query, the COUNT function doesn't filter by the 'check_if_new_customer' flag. I read in this article: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/wizard/page4.html that SUM can be used instead of COUNT in some cases to get more accurate results, however when I try that, I get something very different, it seems to show massive doubling of numbers. I think this may be because I'm summing the UUID that is in the id field instead of counting at that point. Any suggestions on what I could put there to get a count of all of the existing customers vs the new customers?

```
SELECT
  YEAR(so.date_entered),
  so.technical_address_country,
  so.technical_address_state,
  COUNT(so.id) as all_sales,
  COUNT(mf.id) as all_jobs,
  SUM(so.total_value) as all_value,
    COUNT(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=1,so.id,0)) as sales_order_new,
  SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer = 1,so.total_value,0)) as total_value_new,
    COUNT(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=1,mf.id,0)) as jobs_new,
    COUNT(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=0,so.id,0)) as sales_order_existing,
  SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer = 0,so.total_value,0)) as total_value_existing,
    COUNT(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=0,mf.id,0)) as jobs_existing,
    SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=0,mf.id,0)) as jobs_existing_t
FROM 
  sugarcrm2.so_order so 
LEFT JOIN 
  sugarcrm2.mf_job mf on so.id = mf.sales_order_id 
WHERE 
  so.date_entered > "2011-10-30" AND 
    so.technical_address_country IS NOT NULL AND  
  so.technical_address_state IS NOT NULL AND 
  so.deleted = 0 AND 
  so.has_been_promoted = 1 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(so.date_entered),
  so.technical_address_country, 
  so.technical_address_state
ORDER BY 
  so.technical_address_country, so.technical_address_state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `SUM()` like `COUNT()` you will need to pass it either a 1 or 0 so that all of the 1's will sum up to your desired count. So in your example, if you want a sum of all the new jobs you would do this:

> SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=1,1,0)) as jobs_new

or if so.check_if_new_customer always returns a 1 or 0 you could alternatively do this:

> SUM(so.check_if_new_customer) as jobs_new

Answer (score 1):

[`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) returns the number of records for which its argument, if specified, is non `NULL`.  Since its argument in this case is the result of an `IF()` expression (which evaluates to some column's value if true and `0` if false), virtually every record will be counted irrespective of the test condition.

[`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum), as its name suggest, sums the values of its argument.  In this case, it would sum the values of the referenced column whenever the test condition is true.

Apparently neither is what you're after, although your question is rather ambiguous as to what exactly you do want.  At a guess, you might want something like:

```
SUM(so.check_if_new_customer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to sum +1 for every time the joined table's id field is not null.

SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=0 AND mf.id IS NOT NULL,1,0)) as jobs_existing